# How to hide connection string in app config from user

Tags: vb.net, connection-string

All my grids and combo boxes bound to dataset/adapter which the connection string set in app config, but the connection string is included in primary output when installed in my client. i tried to exclude it because the connection string contain my database password, but my app returned an exception.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="HNBS_SALON_SPA.My.MySettings.dbhnbspapuaConnectionString"
        connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=&quot;mydb.accdb&quot;;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=abcdefg"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You're wondering about hiding this Access connection string **within a [tag:vb.net] application**, correct?

Comment: after installing my app in my client pc, i can lookup to the installation folder and open the appconfig file with notepad and read the password. this make my database could be opened and edited easily from outside the app.

Comment: The [first hit on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=vb.net+hide+connection+string) gave me the three answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks to @ashleedawg , I searched more threads and articles about encryption and found some :

https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file

and

[ConnectionStrings in app.config. What about security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204288/connectionstrings-in-app-config-what-about-security?rq=1)

Now I convert the code to vb.net and modify it to my need (section key) and i now be able to encrypt the app.config.

```
    Private Sub EncryptConfigSection()
    Dim Config As Configuration
    Dim Section As ConfigurationSection

    Config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
    Section = Config.GetSection("connectionStrings")
    If (Section IsNot Nothing) Then

        If (Not Section.SectionInformation.IsProtected) Then

            If (Not Section.ElementInformation.IsLocked) Then
                Section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider")
                Section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = True
                Config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full)
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

although it is needed to run the app for at least 1 time to make the encryption run but it's what i need right now.

Comment: You could have an installer run the same code.

Comment: thanks, i'll try it later.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. You can hide the connection string by encrypting it in `web.config`.
>      See it with [**example here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998283.aspx).
> 2. If you mean making `web.config` file invisible for system users, it would make in invisible for your application. If you make it visible for your application, it means any user having sufficient privileges will be able to read. You can only work-around it not having connection string at all in this file. 
>      For example, you could specially design ciphered storage (say, based on `XML` file), decode it on the fly and code assignment of you connection string programmatically in your application.
> 3. **Encryption** will be the best approach to hide the information. Why the connection string kind of information stored in `webconfig` in, there is no need to compile the code again if its changed and its ease to access globally. If Encryption/Decryption method is followed be extra care while you changing the `userid` and `password` in the string.
>      For example you can refer [**this article**](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203213/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021506-1.aspx).

([**Source**](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/152351/Hide-connection-string))

---

### More Information:

- Stack Overflow : [How to securely store a connection string in a WinForms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606892)

Comment: i saw that but i thought it only for asp or web, while i make standard windows application

Comment: There are many other examples on Google if you try to [refine your search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=web+applicatoin+hide+password+connecttion+string+-web+-asp).  You are not the first person to do this.

Comment: What you have linked to is misleading. It is reasonable to encrypt a config file on a server that has limited access, but on a client machine the protection is very limited. If the app can decrypt it then so can anyone else.

Comment: Those links were only examples.  I didn't put much effort into googling for the answer, ***that's the OP's job***, and is **expected prior to posting here**.  See: **["How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/8112776)**  I am confident that this is not the first time someone has needed to prevent users from seeing a connection string

Comment: You're right, it is not the first time. And almost all resources say the same thing you have said and I get **yelled at** for trying to prevent a security vulnerability.

Comment: @Crowcoder ok. Go discuss this with the person who yelled at you.  By the way, you'll notice the OP is nowhere to be seen.  Please try to avoid giving the impression that this a place to drop un-researched/unattempted problems and the users here will solve them.  There are enough poor-quality questions being posted here as it is.  (See the **[graph here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/836890/avg-q-a-average-scores-monthly-month-by-month-comparison-last-10-years#graph)** for proof of the trend.)

Comment: thanks all but I don't think the answer is directly in your link. I asked here because i find it difficult to understand what i have read on some links just like the one you have given. by the way i just found the solution by searching some clue and modify it for my need. i am posting it. the vote down for this question for me is more like " i don't know the answer after searching the google, so vote down".  i don't accept the answer from @ashleedawg because that's not the answer i'm looking for.

Comment: Apologies, I thought you were talking to me and I just expected it since I literally get berated every time I try to tell people it is not safe to use encryption strictly client-side.

Comment: @Goofy_Phie You did more research and found the solution, well done.  By the way I've never used vb.net but as I said, it still had a pretty good idea that this is not a unique issue, and the links provided (although did take my time put together for you) were intended as examples of basic search steps.

Comment: yes, i agree. i did some research before but honestly for more easy way rather than need to encrypt.  that's why my thread title is only to hide not to encrypt